# Linkedin login advertisment page

Tags: android, authentication, linkedin-api

When openning Linkedin login page one gets from their android SDK, sometimes it redirects us to misleading and confusing ad (attached). Does anyone know how can we prevent this? If we talk to LinkedIn, can they turn this monstrosity off?

[image: Linkedin ad]

Comment: I think they do it based on the user-agent header in the HTTP request.  Try changing your user-agent string to something not associated with Android or iPhone and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately a change was pushed last week that caused this to start happening for mobile clients.  We're actively working on getting this fixed.